# Display none mobile and desktop issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

What I am trying to figure out is how to have two things that are shown in desktop disappear in mobile. What is happening right now is that I have two aspects of my code the classes with images and the class titles in desktop and what is hidden (what the user has to click to get to) is the description of the project. My desktop version is perfect and how I want it, but the only issue I am having is that in mobile I ONLY want to show the descriptions of the projects and not the two clickable steps before. I know that this has something to do with display:none; or a combination of display properties but what I have been trying does not seem to work.

I was not sure how to put this in a snippet or in a fiddle because there are multiple html pages as well as a JSON file. So in that case I will link a url to it so that it is accessible.

If this does not make any sense or you need me to clarify I would be more than happy to! I could really use some help with this so if anyone out there has an idea on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

http://sws.mnstate.edu/ry6750sm/data-proj/education2.html

Here is the education.html:

```html
 <body>
  

 <hr class="hr2">
 <section id="content">
      <div id="container">
       <h2 >Class Projects</h2>
<div id="movecontainer">
       <div id="move">
        <div class="third ">
          <div id="classes"><!--was event -->
            <a id="GDES203" href="GDES203.html" ><img src="img/circlecircle.png" alt="GDES203" />GDES203</a>
            <a id="gcom355" href="gcom355.html" ><img src="img/circlecircle.png" alt="GCOM355"  />GCOM355</a>
            <a id="COM230" href="COM230.html" ><img src="img/circlecircle.png" alt="COM230"  />COM230</a>


          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="third ">
          <div id="projects"><!--was sessions -->
            <p>Select a class</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
          <div id="details"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div><!-- #container -->
      
    </section><!-- #content -->

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gcomclasses.js"></script>
 

 
 
</body>
```

Here is the description html:

```html
<body>

    <header>
      
    </header>

    <div id="Fender-Guitar" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Fender Stratocaster Electric Guitar</h3>
      <a href="three-projects/int-com-graph/guitar2.png"><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/int-com-graph/guitar2.png" height="150"/></a>
      <p>The guitar is a Fender Stratocaster Electric Guitar that I replicated in Adobe Illustrator. I used shadows and highlights to create depth for the piece as well as added gradient detail. </p>
    
    </div>

    <div id="Fancy-Fishes" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Fancy Fishes</h3>
     <a href="three-projects/int-com-graph/Hw3-Mclain-graning2 copy.jpg" ><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/int-com-graph/Hw3-Mclain-graning2 copy.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>Fancy Fishes is a clothing line that features the underwater style and I created this piece by using many gradient meshes, a scaling pattern for the fish, and layered meshes for the realistic pearl effect.  </p>
      
    </div>

    <div id="Dragon-Tracks" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Dragon Tracks</h3>
       <a href="three-projects/int-com-graph/covercover.jpg"><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/int-com-graph/covercover.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>This CD cover was inspired by icycles. The way I captured this look was by using photos of melted crayon wax and putting it into Adobe Photoshop and changing the hue to get the desired color. The smoke was created in Adobe Illustrator as a brush to try and create a unique smoked icycle style.   </p>
  
    </div>
    
        <div id="Gelato-Company" class="flex-item">
      <h3>L'Airone Gelato</h3>
      <a href="three-projects/graphic-design/gelato.jpg"><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/graphic-design/gelato.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>This design was for a gelato company that served all its ice cream as coffee flavors. Thus, I tried to create a coffee-oriented design with a logo centered around coffee in an ice cream cone.  </p>
      
    </div>

    <div id="Company-Logo" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Company Logo</h3>
      <a href="three-projects/graphic-design/abstract.jpg"><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/graphic-design/abstract.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>This piece was inspired by the idea of creating a logo for a company with an abstract panda logo. This company's logo is made up of pieces that unify the panda and thus the company.   </p>
      
      
    </div>

    <div id="Band-Logo" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Band Logo</h3>
      <a href="three-projects/graphic-design/abpanC.jpg"><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/graphic-design/abpanC.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>This logo was inspired by the band KISS. If KISS was to have a panda as their mascot then this is the type of logo that they would have. This was made with the crystallize tool in Adobe Illustrator to get the spiky feel.    </p>
      
    </div>


          <div id="Photo-1" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Flower</h3>
       <a href="three-projects/Photography_pics/flower.jpg"><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/Photography_pics/flower.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>This photo was created with a painting with light technique where the camera captures a light pattern through long exposure. The more the light is moved in the shot and the longer the exposure, the lighter and movement of light is captured. This photo was captured with a thirty second exposure and edited in Adobe Photoshop.   </p>
   
    </div>

    <div id="Photo-2" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Graffiti</h3>
      <a href="three-projects/Photography_pics/IMG_0441.jpg"> <img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/Photography_pics/IMG_0441.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>This photo was captured in the heart of downtown Fargo. The graffiti was on a random building from an anonymous artist. So the origins of the art is unknown, however the piece is beautifully painted and was edited in Adobe Photoshop.  </p>
   
    </div>

    <div id="Photo-3" class="flex-item">
      <h3>Grains of Sand</h3>
      <a href="three-projects/Photography_pics/IMG_0505.jpg"><img alt="company logo" src="three-projects/Photography_pics/IMG_0505.jpg" height="150"/></a>
      <p>This photo was captured of a building’s wall in downtown Fargo that was eroding. The intent of the photo was to try and capture the details of the wall so that the viewer could see the grains of sand.     </p>
    
    </div>


  </body>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```js
// NOTE: This example will not work locally in all browsers.
// Please try it out on the website for the book http://javascriptbook.com/code/c08/
// or run it on your own server.

$(function() {                                    // When the DOM is ready
  var projectList;                                      // Declare global variable
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {                   // Before requesting data
      if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {                 // If supported
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json"); // set MIME to prevent errors
      }
    }
  });

  // FUNCTION THAT COLLECTS DATA FROM THE JSON FILE
  function loadClassProjects() {                    // Declare function
    $.getJSON('data/projects.json')              // Try to collect JSON data
    .done( function(data){                      // If successful
      projectList = data;                             // Store it in a variable
    }).fail( function() {                       // If a problem: show message
      $('#classes').html('Sorry! We could not load the Class Projects at the moment');
    });
  }
  loadClassProjects();                              // Call the function


  // CLICK ON THE EVENT TO LOAD A ClassProjects
  $('#content').on('click', '#classes a', function(e) {  // User clicks on event

    e.preventDefault();                                // Prevent loading page
    var loc = this.id.toUpperCase();                   // Get value of id attr

    var newContent = '';                               // Build up ClassProjects by
    for (var i = 0; i < projectList[loc].length; i++) {      // looping through events
      newContent += '<li><span class="software">' + projectList[loc][i].software + '</span>';
      newContent += '<a href="descriptions.html#';
      newContent += projectList[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
      newContent += projectList[loc][i].title + '</a></li>';
    }

    $('#projects').html('<ul>' + newContent + '</ul>'); // Display projectList on page

    $('#classes a.current').removeClass('current');       // Update selected item
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $('#details').text('');                             // Clear third column
  });

  // CLICK ON A SESSION TO LOAD THE DESCRIPTION
  $('#content').on('click', '#projects li a', function(e) { // Click on session
    e.preventDefault();                                     // Prevent loading
    var fragment = this.href;                               // Title is in href

    fragment = fragment.replace('#', ' #');                 // Add space after#
    $('#details').load(fragment);                           // To load info

    $('#projects a.current').removeClass('current');        // Update selected
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });


  
});
```

Here is the JSON:

```js
{
    "GDES203": [
        {
            "software": "Illustrator",
            "title": "Gelato Company"
        },

        {
            "software": "Illustrator",
            "title": "Company Logo"
        },

        {
            "software": "Illustrator",
            "title": "Band Logo"
        }

    ],

    "GCOM355": [
        {
            "software": "Illustrator",
            "title": "Fender Guitar"
        },

        {
            "software": "Illustrator",
            "title": "Fancy Fishes"
        },

        {
            "software": "Indesign Illustrator Photoshop",
            "title": "Dragon Tracks"
        }

    ],
    "COM230": [
        {
            "software": "Photoshop",
            "title": "Photo 1"
        },

        {
            "software": "Photoshop",
            "title": "Photo 2"
        },

        {
            "software": "Photoshop",
            "title": "Photo 3"
        }

    ]

}
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#attended{
margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right:20px;
 font-size:25px;
 margin-top:80px;

}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  height:100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 color: white;

}

.all{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display:block;
}



h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 28px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 225px;
  height: 90px;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;}

h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: -.06em;}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #29BCCA;
  font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}



a {text-decoration: none; color: white;}

.third, .classes {
  width: 320px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;


}


.hr2{
 border: none;  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;  

   width: 70%;               
  color:#485A5F;
   height: 2px;
}

.classes p {border-right: 1px solid #999 ;

   
 }




#content .classes:last-child p {border-right: none;}

.third p {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4em;}

/* Projects */
#classes a {
  font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  display: block;
  height: 120px; width: 100%;}
#classes img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  }
#classes a:hover, #projects a:hover {color: #1DA0A3;}
#projects a {
 font-family: 'Sahitya', serif;
  font-size: 120%;}
#projects p {
  margin-top: 2em;}
#projects ul {
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;}
#projects li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
 
  border-top: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  text-align: left;
  
  }
#projects li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
  padding-top: 1.8em;}
#projects li .software {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  }
#details div {
 
  padding: 1.8em 0 0em 1;}
#details p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0.8em 0 0 2em;}
```

Comment: have you tried with media queries?

Comment: @ananya yes, I'm just confused as to how to block the two first steps and only show the descriptions in mobile

Comment: which 2 steps? can you please explain? Im nt clear about your requirement. Which description you are talking about?

Comment: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: If you click on the url I posted the code greets you with photos and it says select a class one you select a class the descriptions show up. I want in mobile for the photos and the select a class option to disappear so that only the descriptions are present. @Ananya

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */


@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .third:nth-child(1) a img, .third:nth-child(2) p {
        display: none;
    }
}
```